# Properly load file packaged inside .war file

Tags: java, heroku

I have Java Web application that works with `jFuzzyLogic` library which uses `rules.fcl` file which is located at `WEB-INF/rules/rules.fcl`.

On my local server everything seems to work, but when I deploy war to Heroku, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:133)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS.load(FIS.java:143)
net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS.load(FIS.java:130)
com.vukstankovic.professionalorientation.Results.calculation(Results.java:119)
```

At my `Results` at line 119 I'm trying to load `rules.fcl` like this:

```
FIS fis = FIS.load(ctx.getRealPath("WEB-INF/rules/rules.fcl"));
```

At the begining of this method I have this annotation:

```
@Context ServletContext ctx;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream` which would load your files with designed path based on root level of war package:

```java
InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/rules/rules.fcl");
```

Then, it is up to you to use that stream and chain it to load your file content. It should be something like the follwoing if there a `FIS#load` method that accept `InputStream` as paramter:

```java
boolean verbose = true; //Just choose your suitable value (verbose mode or not)
FIS fis = FIS.load(inputStream, verbose);
```

<sup>Just caught the method signature from this [svn repo](http://sensordds.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/JFuzzyLogic/src/net/sourceforge/jFuzzyLogic/FIS.java).</sup>

Comment: Problem is that `FIS.load` expects `String` as argument

Answer (score 0):

Path passed to `ServletContext.getRealPath()` should start with a `'/'` character:

```
FIS fis = FIS.load(ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/rules/rules.fcl"));
```

And also according to the [javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)):

> This method returns `null` if the servlet container cannot translate the virtual path to a real path for any reason (such as when the content is being made available from a `.war` archive).

So if your `.war` archive is not extracted, this method won't work. Make sure your deployed `.war` file gets unpacked.